# Browse external storage for folders and files and read selected file

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I am trying to read a CSV file from local Storage. The problema is that i do dot know yet the file name and the directory. I have tried to look for some examples, but in all of them the file name is already known. How i can access the external Storage, browse and select a directory and then list the files on that directory to select one to use on my CSV reader.

Comment: Can you share some code that you've done?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider

Comment: I haven´t done any code yet, I have tried few examples from GitHub and tutorials, but i did not found something suitable for me. It s the First time i am using local Storage, so i am a bit lost.